# Oracle UpdateXML() add CDATA

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, xmltype

I have a table with an `XMLType` column. I wrote an anonymous block to loop through rows matching a certain criteria, then it'll look at each record and update some of the XML if required.

The original XML stored in the table looks something like this:

`<VALUES><![CDATA['Value']]></VALUES>`

My loop will pull the existing values out of each block like this:

```
SELECT xml.txtValue
  INTO strValue
  FROM my_table s,
       XMLTable('/PATH/*'
                PASSING s.xmlTypeColumn
                COLUMNS txtValue     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)   PATH   'VALUES/text()') xml
 WHERE s.pk = 1234
   AND xml.txtValue like '%Value%';
```

The result is the variable `strValue` contains: 'Value' which I then evaluate and manipulate etc.

Here is a simplified example of the update portion of the script (removed looping and business logic to show my issue with one specific record):

```
DECLARE
   my_xml      XMLTYPE;
   my_new_xml  XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT my_xml_column
     INTO my_xml
     FROM my_table
    WHERE pk = 1234;

   SELECT UPDATEXML (my_xml, '/PATH/VALUES/text()', '''NewValue''')
     INTO my_new_xml
     FROM DUAL;

   UPDATE my_table
      SET my_xml_column = my_new_xml
    WHERE pk = 1234;
END;
```

The result is the specific path in the XML is updated to:

`<VALUES>&apos;NewValue&apos;</VALUES>`

If I change my code as follows:

```
   SELECT UPDATEXML (my_xml, '/PATH/VALUES/text()', '<![CDATA[''NewValue'']]>')
```

The result is the XML is updated to:

`<VALUES>&lt;![CDATA[&apos;NewValue&apos;]]&gt;</VALUES>`

What I *actually* want is:

`<VALUES><![CDATA['NewValue']]></VALUES>`

How can I get the `<![CDATA[ ]]>` wrapper in there properly without `UpdateXML()` escaping it for me?

**NOTE**: I originally found two 12.1.0.2 instances that had this problem, but then I found two 12.1.0.2 instances and one 11.2.0.4 instance that did *NOT* have this problem.

i.e. three instances were able to call:

```
   SELECT UPDATEXML (my_xml, '/PATH/VALUES/text()', '<![CDATA[''NewValue'']]>')
```

...and the result was:

`<VALUES><![CDATA['NewValue']]></VALUES>`

...without the escaped `&apos; &lt; &gt;` characters inserted.

So it seems that `UpdateXML()` may work differently on different Oracle instances, regardless of version number.

Comment: have a look at the XMLCDATA function https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions216.htm. Should just be able to call this with your NewValue.

Comment: Yup, that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Shaun Peterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2833401/shaun-peterson), the answer is:

```
SELECT UPDATEXML (my_xml, '/PATH/VALUES/text()', XMLCdata('''NewValue'''))
  INTO my_new_xml
  FROM DUAL;
```